# Schedulable Batch Errors

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, schedulebatch

I'm trying to write a schedulable batch class that runs every night at midnight that updates these particular fields. I keep recieving these error messages and I dont understand why I keep getting them in the console.

> Line 1 Class LAM_RollupBatch must implement the method:void
>   Database.Batchable.finish(Database.BatchableContext)
>
> Line 41 Expecting ')' but was: 'Batch Class' Line 41 Unexpected token
>   ','. Line 41 Unexpected token ')'. Line 41 Unexpected token ')'.

Here is my code:

```
global class LAM_RollupBatch implements Database.Batchable <sObject> {

    global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;


    global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Parent_Account_for_LAM__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_CCF__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_Usage_kWh__c, Account_Max_Demand_kw__c, AnnualRevenue FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate = TODAY';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope)
    {
        for (Account a : scope)
        {

            a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_CCF__c =  a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_CCF__c+'Rolling 12 Month Total CCF is updated';
            a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c = a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c+'Rolling 12 Month Total Revenue is updated';
            a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Usage_kWh__c  = a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Usage_kWh__c+'Rolling Total Usage kWh is updated';       
            a.AnnualRevenue = a.AnnualRevenue+'Annual Revenue is updated';
            a.Account_Max_Demand_kw__c = a.Account_Max_Demand_kw__c+'Account Max Demand kw has been updated';

            recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;

        }
        update scope;
    }
    global void finsih(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

        System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed');

    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
    {
        Type t = Type.forName('LAM_RollupBatch');
        Database.Batchable<sObject> batchClass = ((Database.Batchable<sObjects>) t.newInstance());
        Database.executeBatch(batchClass, 500);
    }
    ScheduleBatch my = new ScheduleBatch();
    String str = '0 0 0 * * ?';
    System.schedule('Batch Class', str, my);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a typo in the name of your "finish" method name. Additionally, you seem to have included the scheduling of the batch within the scope of the class declaration rather than in a separate method of some form.

By the way, unless you are explicitly wanting the batch to be usable outside any package it is included in, you just need to make the class and the methods public, not global.

Your code, cleaned up, could be like this:

```
public class LAM_RollupBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    private Integer recordsProcessed = 0;

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Parent_Account_for_LAM__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_CCF__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_Usage_kWh__c, Account_Max_Demand_kw__c, AnnualRevenue FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate = TODAY';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
        for (Account a : scope) {
            a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_CCF__c =  a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_CCF__c+'Rolling 12 Month Total CCF is updated';
            a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c = a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c+'Rolling 12 Month Total Revenue is updated';
            a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Usage_kWh__c  = a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Usage_kWh__c+'Rolling Total Usage kWh is updated';       
            a.AnnualRevenue = a.AnnualRevenue+'Annual Revenue is updated';
            a.Account_Max_Demand_kw__c = a.Account_Max_Demand_kw__c+'Account Max Demand kw has been updated';

            recordsProcessed++;
        }

        update scope;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed');
    }
}
```

You should write separate code to schedule it IMHO.

Comment: thanks for your help when I implemented this clean code I receive error messages  in the for loop for the execute method that say illegal assignment from String to Decimal

Comment: Hi. well, I can't see your schema definition. It seems likely you are incorrectly appending your strings to actual numeric values. I recommend checking your schema to see what your field types are and changing the processing to behave correctly.